How to solve this Accenture Coding Round Question
Coding Question
Question 1
Rebound Height
Daniel has a ball. He wants to find the ball's rebound height, which he dropped from height H with an initial velocity V. After the Nth rebound the final velocity of the ball is Vn. Your task is to help him find and return an integer value representing the height to which the ball rebounds after N bounces.
Note:

H' = H x e²n, where H' is the rebound height, H is the initial height, e is

the coefficient of restitution and is the number of bounces

e" = V/Vn, where V is the initial velocity and V is the final velocity


This is the Question I got in Accenture coding round
I solved this question and only 2 testcases passed
I tried rounding off, divide by zero and long/double stuff
I dont know where I went wrong or Is it problem with the question
def fun(in1, in2, in3):
    #int in1 - initial height
    #int in2 - initial velocity
    #int in3 - final velocity
    # this was given in the coding area

    e = in2//in3
    new_e = e**2
    return in1*new_e


The problem is that you first use integer division // to calculate e and then find the rebound height, which introduces some error into the calculation.
Instead, you should first calculate the rebound height and then return its integer value like this:
def fun(in1, in2, in3):
    # int in1 - initial height
    # int in2 - initial velocity
    # int in3 - final velocity
    # this was given in the coding area

    e = in2 / in3

    new_e = e ** 2
    rebound_height = in1 * new_e  # at this point, the rebound height is a float.

    return int(rebound_height)  # return "an integer value representing the height"

